Which perspective is correct for moving source and observer?

A fire engine is moving at 50 m/s and sounding its horn of frequency 1500 Hz. A van in front of the fire engine is moving at 35 m/s in the same direction. What is the frequency that the driver of the van hears? Speed of sound in air = 340 m/s.

I solved this problem using a relative motion perspective, where I considered that since the fire engine is faster than the van, it will eventually catch up to it, making the two vehicles relatively approach each other. This led me to add the observer’s speed $(v_o)$ and subtract the source’s speed $(v_s)$, resulting in a frequency of  $1940 \, \text{Hz}$.
However, the answer key uses an absolute motion perspective, where the van is still moving away from the sound waves at the given instant, even though the fire engine will eventually catch up. So it subtracts both $(v_o)$ and $(v_s)$, resulting  in a frequency of $1578 \, \text{Hz}$.
Which way of thinking about this problem is correct? Thinking about it relatively did not cause an issue in other problems and lead to the correct answer. What am I missing here?

Your approach would work for light (although you would need to use the relativistic Doppler formula). But it does not work for sound. It neglects the asymmetry that is introduced by the presence of the air.
There is a general formula that works for both light and sound. See The Doppler Shift for Sound and Light at mathpages. But note that it is derived in the frame of the medium, which is necessary to identify for waves that propagate at less than $c$.

Could you clarify why neglecting the asymmetry of sound through the medium did not affect the other sound problems I solved, where the source and observer were either both approaching each other, moving away from each other, or one of them was stationary, but it matters in this case?

@HaniIsmael not without actually seeing the other problems.

fair point. I've shared the link to the other problems for your reference. I'd really appreciate a clarification.

@HaniIsmael in 12 the emitter is at rest with respect to the air, and in 13 the receiver is at rest with respect to the air. The difference with this problem is that both are moving with respect to the air
